# query in xml selecting data

Tags: c#, xml

How can I make this command in C# and xml select name where store is equal to 170.

I have this code:

C#:

```
var name = textBox2.Text;
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Work\stores.xml");

var xpath = "//*[text()='" + name + "']";

var result = ((IEnumerable)doc.XPathEvaluate(xpath)).Cast<XElement>().FirstOrDefault();
textBox1.Text = result.Value;
```

XML:

```
<stores>
    <store rollNumer="170">
        <Name>Jonh</Name>
        <Color>Pink</Color>
        <Sell>Sugar</Sell>
    </store>

    <store rollNumer="120">
        <Name>Tedy</Name>
        <Color>Brown</Color>
        <Sell>Rice</Sell>
    </store>
</stores>
```

Thank you

Comment: XElement store = doc.Descendant("store").Where(x => (int)x.Attribute("rollNumer") == 170).FirstOrDefault();  string name = (string)store.Element("Name"); string color = (string)store.Descendent("Color").FirstOrDefault(); string sell = (string)store.Element("Sell");

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda expression to select any xml elements in XDocument.

In your case:

```
var storeElement = doc.Descendants("store").Where(e => e.Attribute("rollNumer").Value == "170").First();
```